# How to present a new view controller in a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

Here is the situation: my app contains a `UITabBarController` with many `UINavigationControllers`, and I want to open a specific one when receiving a notification.

If I want to show a `UINavigationController` that's already in my `UITabBarController` then no problem, I can easily get its index and do it. But I'm struggling with the case where I have to open a `UINavigationController` (or any `UIViewController`) that's not already in it. I don't know what is the way to achieve this. What could I do?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on `.setViewControllers()`.

Suppose your tabbar currently has tabs for `vc1` `vc2` and `vc3`, but you want to display `someOtherVC` which is not currently assigned to a tab.

```
    if let someOtherVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someOtherVC") {

        // append someOtherVC to the tab bar controller's array of view controllers
        self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.append(someOtherVC)

        // show the newly added tab / view controller
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = (self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.count)! - 1

    }
```

and, in `viewDidLoad()` of `someOtherVC`:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // create the new "tab" button
        self.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Other", image: UIImage(named: "otherVCIcon"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "otherVCIcon"))
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In my app, the root view controller is a UINavigation controller.  At a certain point in the app, I need to display a UITabBar.  I tried implementing a UITabBar on a UIView within the navigation hierarchy, as some of the previous posts suggested, and this does work.  But I found that I wanted more of the default behavior that the tab controller provides and I found a way to use the UITabBarController with the UINavigation controller:

1) When I want to display the UITabBarController's view, I do this:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = myUiTabBarControllerInstance;
```

use 1 to show viewControllers in the tabbar

2) When I want to return to where I was in the navigation hierarchy, I do this:

```
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = myNavControllerInstance;
```

use 2 to show viewController out tabbar

Comment: Embed UITabBarController in a navigation controller? Really??